# Compile without linking

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm

I have a project set up with CMake, and I would like to build one object file in the project and output its llvm IR representation, in order to systematically inspect the generated output.

What I have so far is this:

```
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
    separate_arguments(COMPILE_FLAGS UNIX_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
    list(APPEND COMPILE_FLAGS "-S" "-emit-llvm" "-o" "example1.llvm")    

    add_custom_command(
        TARGET example1 #example1 is the target that builds the actual executable 
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
        ARGS  ${COMPILE_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/calculator1.cpp
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Output the llvm IR representation"
    )
endif()
```

Unfortunately `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` does not contain all the arguments passed to clang in the actual compilation. I miss at least the extra include directories, and probably something else.

I tried

```
get_target_property(MYVAR example1 COMPILE_FLAGS)
```

and

```
get_property(
    MYVAR 
    TARGET example1
    PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS )
```

But they both fail.

How do I get all the options passed to the compiler (and not the linker)?

Should I take an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Do you generate Makefile:s out of CMake? In that case you can use the property `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE`:

> RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE Specify a launcher for compile rules.
>
> Makefile generators prefix compiler commands with the given launcher
>   command line. This is intended to allow launchers to intercept build
>   problems with high granularity. Non-Makefile generators currently
>   ignore this property.